# Detect presence of a signature opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

I have an image of a form which contains signatures and I need an automated method of determining if a signature is present in the image. I do not need to match the signature, I just need a basic Boolean response of "yes there is a signature in this image" or "there is no signature in this image." A lot of the resources I've found are used for signature matching (not what I need, as signatures will be different every time) or are just not working.

My basic workflow is I load in the image of the form, crop and grayscale then binarize the image and then use pixel coordinates to crop to specific regions on the form. Below are two examples of cropped images from regions that should contain a signature. The first crop (`signature_1a`) contains a signature, the second crop (`signature_2b`) does not.

[image: cropped image containing signature]

[image: cropped image without a signature]

First I attempted to use `pytesseract.image_to_string()` but then when I tried to check if the output of that was either `!= None` or `== ''` there was no differentiation between the two images.

Next I attempted to count non-white pixels, assuming that the image with the signature would have > 0 non-white pixels while the image without a signature would have 0 but that was not the case.

```
signature_2b = cropped_images['Section 2']['2b']
img = cv2.cvtColor(signature_2b, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
n_white_pix = np.sum(img > 0)
print('Number of non-white pixels:', n_white_pix) # expect it to be 0

Output: Number of non-white pixels: 225663
```

I also tried blob detection but that was also a bust, as it did not detect any blobs in the output image.

```
# Read image
im = cv2.imread("sig_sample.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
 
# Set up the detector with default parameters.
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create()
 
# Detect blobs.
keypoints = detector.detect(im)
 
# Draw detected blobs as red circles.
# cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS ensures the size of the circle corresponds to the size of blob
im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(im, keypoints, np.array([]), (0,0,255), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
 
# Show keypoints
cv2.imshow("Keypoints", im_with_keypoints)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

What can I do to just detect if an image contains a signature or not?

Comment: `np.sum(img > 0)` - you're counting the white pixels.

Comment: @beaker so how do I count the non-white pixels?

Comment: `np.sum(img == 0)`? Or `np.sum(img < threshold)` for some value of `threshold` if you're worried that the non-white pixels may not be exactly 0.

Comment: tesseract is not for handwriting. even just detecting it (vs whatever scribbles/debris is not handwriting) is a challenge.

Comment: Invert your grayscale image before doing np.sum(img > 0) or np.sum(img>some_threshold). It will then be counting the pixels belonging to the signature.

Comment: best you can do with plain image processing is checking whether ANY stuff was scribbled into a specific area. if you need to spot signatures, you need to train AI for that.